# Divsion with no remainder

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, modulus

I am wanting to generate two random numbers
a and b

a divide b should have no remainder

e.g 10/ 5 = 2

```
def calculate(self, *args):
    a = self.a_value.get()
    b = self.b_value.get()
    if a % b == 0:
        c = a // b
        if c == self.answer_value.get():
             print(tk.messagebox.showinfo(title=(f"Answer", {self.answer_value.get()}),
                                         message="You are correct"))
             self.clear_text()
             self.get_random_4()
        else:
             print(tk.messagebox.showinfo(title=(f"Answer ", {self.answer_value.get()}),
                                         message="You are not correct"))
             self.clear_text()
             self.get_random_4()

def get_random_4(self):
    self.a_value.set(random.randint(12, 144))
    self.b_value.set(random.randint(1, 10))
    self.answer_input.delete(0, 'end')
    self.answer_input.focus()
```

my app keeps on generating random numbers but a divided by has remainder.

Please help :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much simpler way of doing it change your number generator to :

```
self.b_value.set(random.randint(1, 12))
self.a_value.set(self.b_value.get() * random.randint(1, 12))
```

This way you grantee that your numbers are divisible by each other

Comment: Hi @Karan,       thank you. your codes do work. i have tried to upvote your answer but because i am new, it doesnt seem to happen.